# multiple webmaster properties http and https to be linked with single google analytics account

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

We are in **transition of migrating our site from http - > https**

So as transition takes some time to reflect and also we are doing it in phases. We are maintaining both http and https in webmaster.

But we have single property maintained on google analytics account for both http and https. We want to **link webmaster with google analytics for search queries reflection in GA**, so that we can play around with that and set our analytics reports that requires queries vs different matrices.

**Google analytics is allowing one webmaster property to be linked to GA**. So how can we link both http and https to my single GA account as ideally it is one site w.r.t GA.

What is the ideal solution for the above problem we are facing ?

Comment: I am not sure why this question is not getting enough attention. I up-voted because it is a good question and partially because it should have more attention. I just wish I had an answer for you.

Comment: Yes, and its not a hypothetical situation. its a practical problem we are facing. Let's hope people try to answer it.

Comment: Push come to shove, you can always offer a bounty!

Comment: It is a perfectly valid question that will help others. No doubt.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question but I think the short answer is "you can't" for the reasons you've described. GA doesn't seem to differentiate by http/https but by site identification which I've personally observed is the same.

The only way you're going to differentiate is to have two different domains. For example:

```
www.example.com (for http traffic, your present site)
secure.example.com (for https traffic that you are migrating towards)
```

Behind that you can obviously have a single code base serving them each. In fact, past the front page you can redirect back into a single site (so that Google doesn't think you're scamming it with duplicated content). Once you have enough data you can merge it all in to the final site with http redirects.